# Job para gravar dados de uma query em um arquivo XML

Tags: sql-server

Preciso gravar o resultado de uma consulta em um XML através de um job que vai rodar diariamente agendado no SQL Server.
A procedure já trás o resultado no formato do XML com as tags, em uma variável.
Só preciso jogar o conteúdo dessa variável no XML.
Qual a melhor forma de gerar esse XML?
Como eu defino o caminho que o XML será gravado e como eu defino o nome do arquivo?

Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Bom, basicamente é usando o comando [`xp_cmdshell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175046(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(8000) = 'echo ' + @xml + ' > c:\meus\diretorios\teste.txt';

EXEC xp_cmdshell @command;
```